# How do I express the region bounded by $z=x^2, z+y=1, z-y=1$ as a z-simple triple integral?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

I've been able to figure out the y-simple and x-simple triple integrals, but I'm having trouble with the z-simple one. I split the region in half over the x-axis, from what I can see, the projection onto the xy-plane of this is a rectangle of $[-1,1] \times [0,1]$ and $x^2 \leq z \leq 1-y$.

Comment: Are you looking to calculate the volume of the region?

Comment: @nickalh yes, sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: What does $z$-simple triple integral mean?

Comment: I think he means "z-simple region".  For volume of a 3-d shape using a double integral, that would enable us to setup the integral by projecting onto the $z=0$ plane.  The integrand would be $z_{top} - z_{bottom}$. 
 Contrast that with a region that has holes or intersections.
I'm not sure "z-simple triple integral" is an actual term.

This attempts to define a simple area for 2d shapes.

Comment: A more intuitive relevant explanation of a z simple region requires that if we draw a line segment parallel to the z-axis, the region may not start, stop, then start again.

Comment: @Jirki Lahtonen Why did you delete your answer? I thought it was an excellent answer.

Comment: @nickalh The iterated integral i first suggested was just wrong. I realized that it was not right, but my first attempt at fixing it was equally misguided, so I deleted it to be able to think it through. Meanwhile Graham Kemp fixed the problems, so I undeleted. All is good now, I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not an answer. Just posting an image that hopefully makes it easier to grasp which region exactly is supposed to be covered. Normally I would add a picture to the question body, but this time I use a CW answer, because the region may still be in question (and hence my picture misleading).

[image]

More often than not a bounded region is intended. My guess (looking at the picture) is the region above the surface $z=x^2$ and below both the planes $z=1\pm y$. I might write the integral of the function $f(x,y,z)$ over that region as the iterated integral
$$
\int_{x=-1}^1\int_{z=x^2}^1\int_{y=z-1}^{1-z}f(x,y,z)\,dy\,dz\,dx,
$$
but I don't know what the OP means by $z$-simple?

---

If we want an iterated integral with $z$-integration being the first (= the innermost), then I think it would be
$$
\int_{x=-1}^1\int_{y=x^2-1}^{1-x^2}\int_{z=x^2}^{1-|y|}f(x,y,z)\,dz\,dy\,dx.
$$
The reasoning is that the projection $(x,y)$ on the plane $z=0$ of any point in the region must be between the parabolas $y=x^2-1$ and $y=1-x^2$. Please check :-)

If you want to calculate the last iterated integral, you  may need to split it into two regions according to the sign of the $y$-coordinate. Business as usual.

Comment: My goal was mostly to post the image. I added the iterated integral as an afterthought, and did a piss-poor job :-( Thankfully Graham Kemp edited in the correct boundaries.

Comment: As OP mentioned in the comments, $f(x,y,z) = 1$ because this is integral is an ordinary volume of the region.  Then instead of two integrals to workout the absolute value sign use the symmetry.  Meaning double the integral and use $y =0$ for one of the y-limits of integration.  Presumably we'll choose $y:0\rightarrow 1-x^2$ Then y is positive on the relevant domain and $1-|y| = 1-y$.  Yes, maybe, no?

Answer (score 2):

The planes $z+y=1$ and $z-y=1$ intersect at $\langle x, 0, 1\rangle$; a line parallel to the $x$-axis, 1 unit distant in the $z$ direction.

The $xz$ plane parallel cross-sections of curve $z=x^2$ are parabola with minima along the line $\langle 0,y,0\rangle$; the $y$-axis.

Therefore the shape which these planes and curve bound has an edge parallel to the $x$-axis at height $z=1$, two flat sides sloping down at $45^\circ$ angles to meet the parabolic-curved base which has a keel along the $y$-axis.

$$\{\langle x,y,z\rangle: -1\leq x\leq 1~,~x^2\leq z\leq 1~,~z-1\leq y\leq 1-z\}$$

The projection of this 'lemon-wedge' onto the $xy$ plane is not a rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to figure out that we want the parabolic sheet $z = x^2$ to be below the "roof-like" double-planes $ z = 1 - y $ and $ z = 1 + y$.

Since $ z = x^2 $, then we must have

$ z \le 1 - y $

$ z \le 1 + y $

i.e.

$ x^2 \le 1 - y $

$ x^2 \le 1 + y $

The first one gives us

$ y \le 1 - x^2 $

The second one give sus

$ y \ge x^2 - 1 $

Hence the boundaries are

$ x^2 - 1 \le y \le 1 - x^2 $

Since we must have $(1 - x^2) \ge (x^2 - 1)$, then $x^2 \le 1 $ i.e. $x \in [-1, 1] $

So, to calcualte the volume, we have the following

$ V = \displaystyle \int_{x=-1}^{1} \int_{y=x^2 - 1}^{1 - x^2} \int_{z = x^2 }^{1 - |y| } \ dz \ dy \ dx $